# Snort installation on RHEL 6.2 64 bit

Tags: rhel, snort, daq-mx

I am installing snort on RHEL 6.2

I am trying to install DAQ.

I am running

make install

and getting below error:

RCE -module -export-dynamic -avoid-version -shared -L/usr/lib -ldnet -o daq_ipq.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/daq daq_ipq_la-daq_ipq.lo -lipq -L/usr/lib -ldnet ../sfbpf/libsfbpf.la )
libtool: relink: gcc -shared  .libs/daq_ipq_la-daq_ipq.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lipq -ldnet -L/usr/local/lib -lsfbpf    -Wl,-soname -Wl,daq_ipq.so -o .libs/daq_ipq.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libdnet.a(addr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/libdnet.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool: install: error: relink`daq_ipq.la' with 
the above command before installing it
make[2]: *** [install-pkglibLTLIBRARIES] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/daq-0.6.2/os-daq-modules'

make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/daq-0.6.2/os-daq-modules'

make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this, it worked:

```
    $tar zxvf /root/snort-packages/libdnet-1.12.tgz
    $cd libdnet-1.12
    $ ./configure "CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -O2" --prefix=/usr
    $make
    $make install
    $ yum install libdnet-devel
    $ locate libdnet
    $ ln -s libdnet.1 libdnet.so.1
    $ cp /usr/lib64/libdnet.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libdnet.so.1
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$tar zxvf /root/snort-packages/libdnet-1.12.tgz
$cd libdnet-1.12
$ ./configure "CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -O2" --prefix=/usr
$make
$make install
$ yum install libdnet-devel
$ locate libdnet
$ ln -s libdnet.1 libdnet.so.1
$ cp /usr/lib64/libdnet.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libdnet.so.1
```